# Archiving zip files from Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, zip, artifact

I have a Jenkins pipeline which runs a bunch of postman collections using [newman](https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman#command-line-options).

```bash
newman run \"collections/${npm_config_collection}.postman_collection.json\" --color off -e \"environments/TEST.postman_environment.json\" --reporters cli,junitfull,htmlextra --reporter-junitfull-export newman/${npm_config_collection}.xml --env-var access_token=$TOKENSERVICE
```

Since this produces a lot of html files (because of the htmlextra reporter) that cannot be viewed by clicking the links in artifacts, because of som Jenkins settings. To ease this, I added a post action which zips all the html (as well as the junit xml) files generated, to enable easier download, and proper viewing. BUT. Jenkins apparently shows all the html files, which is not what I want.
Can I add something to `archiveArtifacts` to avoid Jenkins expanding the zip file?
[image: links on main job page]
[image: clicked on Last Successful Artifacts]

```
post {
        always {
            echo ' * *  Publishing JUnit results'
            junit testResults: 'newman/*.xml', skipPublishingChecks: true, allowEmptyResults: true
            echo ' * *  Zipping HTMLExtra results'
            script {
                sh script: " zip newman/\$(date +'%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')_htmlreports.zip newman/*.html"
                sh script: " zip newman/\$(date +'%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')_junitreports.zip newman/*.xml"
            }
            echo ' * *  Publishing results as Zip file(s)'
            archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'newman/*.zip', allowEmptyArchive: true
        }
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't look like `archiveArtifacts` lets you change Jenkins UI behavior. As a workaround you could create an archive in a format that Jenkins doesn't understand, such as 7-zip.

Comment: @zett42 i considered that. If it is present on the build images we use I might just do that.